# How many threads to use

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing

I am writing a web scraper and would like to use multiple threads to speed it up. What is a good number of threads to use in such an application on a quad-core processor? I know that if the threads were all constantly processing with no I/O, there would be no point in using more than 4 threads. In this situation though, most of the time is spent waiting for network responses. So how do we evaluate how many threads to use?

Comment: I think that this is something you're really going to want to determine empirically.

Comment: So there's not even a general way to reason about this, it all depends on how long the network requests are taking? Am I correct though in thinking that there will be some point where too many threads are actually slowing the app down?

Comment: There's nothing that says a thread can only handle a single I/O operation at a time.  You can multiplex non-blocking I/O (e.g. via select() or poll()) or implement asynchronous I/O so that each thread is handling dozens or hundreds of network requests at a time.  You can then spawn as many threads as you have cores, and tune your program's maximum-simultaneous-requests-per-thread parameter until you are reasonably close to maximum throughput.